# add google search box to my site

Tags: search-box

I've been researching how to add a Google search box to my site. Basically, the text box and a 'Go' button, which will search the web - except from my site. I used to see these every where.

Come to think of it now though I haven't seen it in a long time. And all the stuff I've come across in research is from early 2010 at the latest. Some searches say Google deprecated the API for what I'm looking for in 2009?

Is it still possible to get code for putting in a Google search on your page? Do you know where? Bing or Yahoo would do, too. Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Google Custom Search Engines - http://www.google.com/cse/all

Answer (score 0):

Try the google jsapi, look at the Hello World - Google  Web Search API Sample and adjust to your layout, 
https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/

Comment: Like I said, too much of their stuff is being deprecated. Mustn't appeal to them anymore. Bing looks straight forward, so think I'll go with that.